# How to find source dimension of a linked dimension in SSAS?

Tags: ssas, cube, dimensions

I have a SSAS Solution with large number of SSAS Projects. Some projects have Linked Dimensions linking to Original Dimensions in the same Solution. I used to find the Original Dimension by expanding all the Projects then all the Dimensions and then visually inspecting them. If the Dimension has a Dimension Structure that is editable, then I know that it is the source dimension. But this process is too tedious when we have large number of Projects with lots of Dimensions within them.

Is there a quicker way to find source dimension of a Linked Dimension? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a quicker method for myself. It is similar to adding New Linked Dimension. Following are the steps.

1. For the project that we have a linked dimension, Right Click **Dimensions** folder.
2. Click **New Linked Dimension**. We will see Linked Object Wizard.
3. Click **Next**. We will see **Select a Data Source window**. We will see list of available Data Sources. These Data Sources point to the Cubes that has Original Dimension.
4. If there are many Data Sources, select **first Data Source** and click **Next**. If you see a dimension with same name as your Linked Dimension, this is your Original Dimension.
5. If you don't find, click **Back**, select **next Data Source**, click **Next** and see if the Original Dimension is there?
6. **Note** the Data Source in which you found the Original Dimension. This **Data Source** shows the Cube/Project that has the Original Dimension.

Cheers :)